# Java library maintenance/changes possible without impact to application using it?

Tags: java

I have a project (main application) that uses a library jar file rev1.0 (added as a referenced library in the Java build path).

I have created my main application as a runnable jar using the export feature in eclipse. The application is to be used by others in the same host.

I am curious if I have updated my library jar to rev1.1 with bug fixes etc, is there a way to deploy the updated jar/library without re-exporting the main application as a jar? I tried re-exporting the main application and it works.

Comment: Details will matter here... does your exported jar file reference the 3rd party library by filename?  or do you just run it with a specific directory in the classpath, or a script, etc

Comment: I am referencing the 3rd party library jar by filename in the Eclipse -> Java build path.

Answer (score 0):

If the main application references the other JAR directly and is not a "fat JAR" that includes the other within its own JAR, then yes, you can update the other until some significant breaking change happens (rename a package, remove a method/class, etc).

You will need to restart the main application to pick up new changes in the other, though

Comment: Thanks for the advise. How can I reference the other Jar directly in my Main application Jar? Is it possible to configure into the main jar with Eclipse. 
I could do this with some success from the command line:

1. javac -cp "ref_lib classpaths" main_app.java (1 time)

2. java -cp "ref_lib classpaths" main_app (Each time I want to run the app)
If I replace the ref lib jar file, running the app using command #2 will show the changes in the updated ref lib jar.
Just wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: The better way would be to use Maven/Gradle to manage your dependencies rather than the IDE (Eclipse), then let the IDE use those build tools to download and cross-reference needed libraries and manage their versions. That way, you could hand your code to somebody not using Eclipse, and it should still build, run, and they can edit the code themselves